# Filter out events during ingestion in druid

Tags: druid

I am ingesting data into druid database event by event, but I want to delete all the events which are specific to a particular user.

For ex. while ingesting data I want to delete events for all the entries having name="Ram"

Comment: Can you please share more detailed information on how you are ingesting data into druid?

Comment: Through kafka indexing service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filters` property of `transformSpec` to filter out events during ingestion. This is the standard way to specify filters in ingestion spec. According to docs,

> Transform specs allow Druid to filter and transform input data during ingestion.

Any [Druid filter](http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/filters.html) can be used in `transformSpec`. For ex. in this case to filter out specific name `transformSpec` will be something like this:

```
"transformSpec": {
    "filter": {
       "type": "not",
       "field": {
          "type": "selector",
          "dimension": "name",
          "value": "Ram"
       }
    },
    "transforms": []
}
```

More details on transform spec can be found here: [Transform Spec Documentation Link](http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/transform-spec.html)

Comment: Can I do it someway dynamic? Because If my system removed 4 users how will I let druid know about this? Or can I update any record in druid?(Not lookup)

Comment: If you can have any field in your CSV file like an active/inactive flag then it will be so easy to have a filter on that column and filter events while performing ingestion.

Comment: But if the user goes inactive after a month I injested the data. Then what would be the solution.

Comment: Then why don’t you use filters at the time of querying data? If you do that then you do not need to update your data and you will have more control over the data filtering.